# XOR operator not evaluating correctly in C++

Tags: c++, xor

I'm building a BigInt class from scratch in C++, but something is driving me nuts: my XOR isn't working properly, and I have no idea why.  I was hoping someone could enlighten me.  Below is a minimal working example:

```
class BigInt
{
    private:
        bool pos;
        int size;  // Number of binary digits to use
        short compare(BigInt input);
    public:
        BigInt(long long input, int inSize) { pos = true; size = inSize; }
};

short BigInt::compare(BigInt input)
{
    // Partial compare function for minimal working example
    // Return:
    //         1: (*this) > input
    //         0: (*this) == input
    //        -1: (*this) < input

    string a = (*this).toDecimal(), b = input.toDecimal();
    bool c = (*this).size > input.size, d = (*this).pos ^ input.pos;

    bool thispos = (*this).pos, inpos = input.pos;
    bool xorpos = (thispos != inpos);

    bool x = true, y = true;
    bool z = x ^ y;

    if ((*this).size > input.size || (*this).pos != input.pos)
        return 1 - ((*this).pos ? 0 : 2);
    else if ((*this).size < input.size)
        return -1 + ((*this).pos ? 0 : 2);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a breakpoint on the first if statement.  Below is what I have on my watch list.

```
    thispos true    bool
    inpos   true    bool
    xorpos  true    bool
    x   true    bool
    y   true    bool
    z   false   bool
```

Anyone know what's going on?  I'd rather avoid kluging my if statement.  I've never had a problem with such simple usage of my XOR.

As far as I can tell, there should be nothing wrong, but there's something about these values that just won't evaluate the way they're expected to.

Edit: Changed code to minimal working example.

Comment: What is your output and expected output?

Comment: `(*this).` ... I'm guessing this is *not* what you want. Just `size` or `pos`. If you *must* refer to `this`, it would be `this->`

Comment: @crashmstr, `this->` is equivalent to `(*this).`

Comment: I believe the OP's implied question is, "Why is `xorpos` true, when `z=x^y` is false?"

Comment: What is the type of BigInt::pos? How is BigInt::pos initialized?

Comment: @remyabel I would expect (true ^ true) to evaluate to false.  It doesn't for xorpos.  Two lines of code later, it does.  I can get by with ((*this).pos != input.pos) just fine, and I have changed it that way so I can keep working... I'm just utterly lost why the xor operator doesn't appear to be doing it's job.

Comment: @Csq BigInt::pos is a bool.  It's initialized to true in all constructors - only set to false manually for now.

Comment: I suggest providing a minimal working example so others can try it out. (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Csq I've made an edit to my post to include one.

Comment: @sflancer06 A minimal working example is a code that I copy and paste to the compiler and it prints "OKAY" or "NOTOKAY". After I extend your code with a `main` function, make `compare`˙public, add a semicolon after the class, create two `BigInt` instances (these should have been done by you) and stop the program at the `if`, my `xorpos` variable is `false`, as expected. I still assume that you have an initialization/invalid memory problem and therefore your `bool`s are somehow neither zero nor one.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error by filling out the given code to form a compilable test case either. One possibility is that since none of the variables in your watch window seem to be used outside of the four lines defining them, you're being fooled by optimizations. Start by giving us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (note the **self-contained** portion, which means we can copy, paste, and compile, like @Csq said).

Answer (score 7):

Well, even though `^` is a bitwise xor operator, your initializations

```
bool thispos = (*this).pos, inpos = input.pos;
```

are required to convert the source values to `bool` type. Values of `bool` type are guaranteed to act as either `0` or `1` in arithmetic contexts. This means that

```
bool xorpos = thispos ^ inpos;
```

is required to initialize `xorpos` with `false` if both `thispos` and `inpos` were originally `true`.

If you observe different behavior, it might be a bug in your compiler. Integral-to-`bool` conversion might be implemented incorrectly or something like that.

Another opportunity is that someone "redefined" the `bool` keyword by doing something like

```
#define bool unsigned char
```

This will disable the proper `bool` semantics in the first pair of initializations and cause the bitwise nature of `^` to affect the result.

Comment: +1 This is a good hypothesis and accounts for the OP's observed behavior. For instance, `1` and `2` are both `true` in a boolean context, but `1^2=3` which is also true in a bitwise sense but should be false in a boolean xor sense.

Comment: BigInt.pos is a bool type, so I wouldn't think that was an issue and the keyword was never redefined.  Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, this doesn't account for the odd behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply do `x != y`? This is more consistent with your types as well.

Comment: I've since changed it to that so I could continue working, but I'd still like to know what was going on with (x ^ y).

Comment: Well, I should have tried compiling immediately after that change.  Turns out that (thispos != inpos) still evaluates incorrectly.  What on earth is going on?

Comment: @sflancer06: Post a compilable example with your exact values and we'll take look.